# How to fix the x-axis value in the Plotly Graph Object?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I am creating a graph which uses few summarised value to be shown on plot. I need my x-axis to be constant from 1 to 30, fix it. So when the horizontal bars come up it will always be less than or equal to 30.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
df_prev_weather_final_sum = pd.read_csv("/content/sample_data/weather_sum_sample.csv")
print(df_prev_weather_final_sum.head())
weather_fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(
                x = df_prev_weather_final_sum["values"],
                y = df_prev_weather_final_sum["index"],
                orientation = 'h',
                marker_color='indianred'
            ))
weather_fig.update_layout(
    title={
        'text': "Weather",
        'y':0.9,
        'x':0.5,
        'xanchor': 'center',
        'yanchor': 'top'},
    yaxis_title="Port-Shipper",
    xaxis_title="Number of Days",
    template = "plotly_dark")
weather_fig.show()
```

[image: My data]

[image]

How I can make the 'number of days' axis fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the `xaxis` range using `update_xaxes`:

```
weather_fig.update_xaxes(range=[1,30], dtick=1)
```